# Releasing of strings

Tags: objective-c

I got a doubt that when should the strings are released.I am not made any allocation to the string is there any necessary to release the string?

Comment: Hello, maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602178/when-to-release-a-nsstring-in-iphone

Comment: This may help also: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 0):

No if you do not "allocate" the string they are auto released.
for example

```
NSString *aTestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@",@"World"];
```

This string is auto released, so you do not have to call [aTestString release];

If you would do:

```
NSString *aTestString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello %@",@"World"];
```

Then you would need to release it by [aTestString release]; because you manually allocated.
Therefore it is wise to autorelease it, so you do not have to think of it later on

```
NSString *aTestString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello %@",@"World"] autorelease];
```

But that would just be the same as the first piece of code I gave ya.
Back to the point, no you do not have to manually release it as long as you do not allocate it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the string via a call to `alloc`, `new`, or a method containing `copy`?  Did you explicitly `retain` the string yourself?  If you got the `NSString` from a `CFStringRef`, did you create the `CFStringRef` with a function that included `create`?  If not, you don't have to do anything.  [If you did, you have to either `release` or `autorelease` the string.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW2)

Answer (score 0):

Object allocation/deallocation rules

You need to call `[Object release]` if and only if:

- You called `[Object alloc]`
- You called `[Object retain]`
- You called `[Object new]`

If you did not explicitly allocate or retain the object, then you need to release it.  If you got the object via a class method, the method did something like this: `return [[[Object alloc] init] autorelease];`.  This allocates a new object, but is autoreleased when the NSAutoReleasePool next gets a chance.